# Swapping references in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

Ok, I was misunderstanding the problem. After reading it a couple of times I figured out `randInt` is actually the method itself i am using to populate the array. So when it says to call `randInt` its some sort of recursive call I think. This is somehow what it should look like:

```
  static int[] randInt(int i, int j) {
    int[] temp = new int[(j - i) + 1];
    for ( i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        temp[i] = i + 1; // here i populate the array
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp)); // this prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for ( i = 1; i < j;i++){
        swapReferences(temp[i], temp[randInt(0,i)] ); //this is some sort of recursive call that swaps the references 
        // btw that statement does not compile, how can i pass a method as a parameter?



    }
    return temp;
}

static void swapReferences(int a, int b) { //these parameters are wrong, need to be changed
   //Method to swap references

}
```

Sorry for the confusion, but I think thats how it should be correctly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not its a different problem.

Comment: You'd think so, but you'd be wrong.

Comment: Different _scenario_, same problem.

Comment: You are passing the int value in each array to the swap method _by value_, so any operations you perform on the ints `a` and `b` are effectively erased as soon as the methods ends. The top answer in Sotirios' link goes over this situation. The solution is to create a `swap` method that takes an array and two indices as parameters, then swap the values in the input array using the given indices.

Answer (score 2):

Java is pass-by-value, so reassigning the parameters as you try to do will not work.

What you need to do is to have the array itself and two integer indices as parameters:

```
 int randInt = generate.nextInt(j-i) + 1; //this is gonna generate a # within the range of the array (so if array is size 5, generates something 1-5)
 for ( i = 1; i < j;i++){
        swapReferences(temp, i, randInt); //and this is my attempt at swapping the references
        randInt = generate.nextInt(i) + 1 ;
  }

  static void swapReferences(int[] array, int a, int b){
     int x = array[a];
     array[a] = array[b];
     array[b] = x;

 }
```

You *can* mutate parameters such as arrays passed into a method, as is being done here, but you can't reassign the parameters themselves.

Comment: Ah you were faster and more succinct than me +1!

Comment: This works correctly as it is, but the book for some reason wants me to implement it another way. I have edited the original post so you can see exactly what is being asked.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the case for your book, but I remember when I was in college some of the code in the books I had for class just didn't work as written. I remember one book that was clearly translated to Java from C, but poorly. So many of the methods didn't work without a bit of manipulation.

Comment: If the book is suggesting a method with the signature as shown, it probably is indeed a bad translation from another language that works differently.  Perhaps you should throw it out and get a book by someone who actually knows Java.

Comment: @DonRoby I think I may have misunderstood the problem initially. I have edited the first post. Maybe it makes more sense now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, no.  It makes a bit less sense now.  You've got a method that returns an `int[]` which you're trying to call recursively in a place that needs an `int` and not an array.

I've got no clue what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @DonRoby The swapReferences method parameters were defined by me, since I do not know how to pass the parameters the book is asking me to pass. The parameters can be changed to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are just changing the ints that a and b are pointing to, but not what the indicies the array is pointing to. You need to change your `swapReferences` method to take the array as input, and something like the indicies to swap

```
static void swapReferences(int[] arr, int indexA, int index B){
    int x = arr[indexA];
    a = arr[indexB];
    b = x;
    arr[indexA] = a;
    arr[indexB] = b;
}
```

or

```
static void swapReferences(int[] arr, int indexA, int indexB){
    int x = arr[indexA];
    arr[indexA] = arr[indexB];
    arr[indexB] = x;
}
```